# Array.prototype.reduce function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, reduce

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
return Math.max(a, b);
});
```

I'm going through MDN docs REDUCE function, In the above code snippet I was just wondering what does function(a,b) do. How it works will it go through like

```
function (1,2)
{

}

function(2,3)
{

}

function(3,1)
{

}
```

Also I found one more example which sums up all the elements in the array

```
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var result = numbers.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    return accumulator + currentValue;
},0);


console.log(result);
```

So in the above example ,

1. how does a function instantly knows that it first argument is an accumulator ??
2. In first iteration what’s the value of accumulator and current value (I’m assuming function(0,1))
3. What happens if I don’t give the initial value (here it is 0) . Is this initial value is something which will be stored into the accumulator in first iteration ??

Could someone  help me in understanding this function ???

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation of the `reduce` method? It answers your questions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a

Comment: "I'm going through MDN docs REDUCE function" so I assume that is the exact reference. It seems that the question is more "what is the _implementation_ of `reduce`"? Maybe?

Comment: `[1,2,3].reduce((a,b) => { console.log("a & b = ",a,b); return Math.max(a,b); })`  IOW:  (1,2) (2,3) = 3

Answer (score 2):

> how does a function instantly knows that it first argument is an accumulator

It is the responsibility of the person who writes the function (i.e. you) to write a function that expects the first argument to be the accumulator.

As the MDN documentation you mention says, that is what the reduce function will pass as the first argument.

> In first iteration what’s the value of accumulator and current value

As the documentation says, the first time it is called, the accumulator will be set to the `initialValue` which will be the first element in the array if you don't specify otherwise.

Likewise, the current value will be the current value being processed in the array.

> What happens if I don’t give the initial value (here it is 0)

Quoting the documentation you referenced: *If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used.*

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think you are conceptually missing a step here. In the docs on MDN you'll note that the callback function that you pass to your reducer function can accept up to 4 arguments (accumulator, current value, current index, array reduce was originally called on). Commonly you will see the reducer using only the accumulator and current value arguments in the callback function. The accumulator is the accumulated result of previous iterations, the current value is the value at the index the reducer is currently iterating on.

```

```
// ES6
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => Math.max(accumulator, currentValue);

// OR OLDER
const reducer = function(accumulator, currentValue) {
  // return whichever is higher 
  return Math.max(accumulator, currentValue);
}
const arr = [1,2,3];
let result = arr.reduce(reducer, 0);
// (0, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 3) -> result = 3;
// more interesting
const arr_2 = [5, 1, 6, 7, 4, 9, 2, 8];
let result_2 = arr_2.reduce(reducer, 0);
// (0, 5)->(5,1)->(5,6)->(6,7)->(7,4)->(7,9)->(9,2)->(9,8)->result = 9
```

The reducer callback is a comparator function that performs an evaluation based on the accumulated value and the current array index and then returns the result.

array.prototype.reduce uses this callback function with an optional base value (0 in my example) to reduce the contents of the array down to a single value.

For example, if you wanted to add all the numbers in an array you would:

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
let result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => cur + acc, 0);
// (0, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (3, 3) -> result = 6
```